# /var/www owned by my user, cant send files to trash

Tags: apache2, trash

I changed ownership of /var/www to username:username since im using it only for development but when i try to delete something it wont send the files to the trash but asks me to permanently delete them.

Comment: if you type `ls -al` is there a file called `.trash-1000` in it?  If not could you try making this file and see if that helps (`touch /var/www/.trash-1000`)?

Comment: there is one inside /var/www called "Trash-1000", 775 permissions owned by my user and group (same as the content of /var/www)

Comment: hmm, mine are 700 and owned by my user and group, but I don't see how that would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PARTIAL SOLUTION

I tested here, and had the same problem.

You need to create a `.Trash-1000`(*) in the highest folder in this filesystem. In my case, it was /

so I ran `sudo mkdir /.Trash-1000` and `chown user:user /.Trash-1000`. Nautilus no longer complains, and it sends the files to the Trash folder.

However ... They dont show up in my trash (via GUI). I just know they are there because I went and checked

(*) actually, its `.Trash-UID` , where the UID can be found using the command `id`

Comment: isn't it weird though? why wouldn't the files be sent to the user's trash? im pretty sure the 'gui trash' that you are about is the one dedicated to your user/uid.

Comment: well ... keeping a Trash for each file system kinda makes sense (given that some file systems are thumbdrives)

But I have no idea were the user can see the deleted items ...